# Не выбирается первый чекбокс. Почему?

Tags: javascript, html

Здравствуйте. Подскажите, почему не выбирается первый ключевой чекбокс   ?

```js
function inver_checkbox(name_form_inv) {

  var obj_form_checked = document.forms[name_form_inv]; //.form_checkbox_object;

  for (i = 0; i < obj_form_checked.elements.length; i++) {
    if (obj_form_checked.elements[i].type == 'checkbox') {
      if (obj_form_checked.elements[i].checked) {
        obj_form_checked.elements[i].checked = false;
      } else
        obj_form_checked.elements[i].checked = true;
    }

  }


  return (false);
}
```

```css
.dialog-msg {
  max-height: 400px;
  overflow: auto;
}

.FS18 {
  font-size: 18px;
}

.user-contact a.btn {
  color: #fff;
}

.panel-msg-btn {
  margin: 0 0 10px 0;
  background-color: #f0f5f9;
}

.table-filter-msg {
  background-color: #fff;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #e3eef5;
}

.table-filter-msg tbody tr:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: #f0f5f9;
}

.table-filter-msg tbody tr td {
  border-top-color: #e3eef5;
}

.table-filter-msg tbody tr.selected td {
  background-color: #e3eef5;
}

.table-filter-msg .media-photo {
  -webkit-border-radius: 50% !important;
  -moz-border-radius: 50% !important;
  border-radius: 50% !important;
}

.table-filter-msg .media .title {}

.table-filter-msg .media a {
  color: inherit;
}
```

```html
  <link href="http://koty-online.ru/templates/adaptive/boostrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <form method="post" name="del_dialogs">
    <table class="table panel-msg-btn text-right">
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td class="col-lg-1 col-md-1 col-sm-1 col-xs-1 text-center">
            <div class="checkbox M0 marginTB10">
              <label class="M0 MT5 vibrate">
                <input type="checkbox" onclick="inver_checkbox(&quot;del_dialogs&quot;);" value="" class="vibrate">
                <span class="cr"><i class="cr-icon glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></i></span>
              </label>
            </div>
          </td>
          <td class="col-lg-11 col-md-11 col-sm-11 col-xs-11">
            <div class="btn-group">
              <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm vibrate"><span title="Ваше сообщение" class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span> Удалить </button>
            </div>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
    <div class="table-container">
      <table class="table table-filter-msg">
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td class="VAM col-lg-1 col-md-1 col-sm-1 col-xs-1 text-center">
              <div class="checkbox M0">
                <label class="M0 vibrate">
                  <input type="checkbox" name="del_dialog_one[]" value="22" class="vibrate">
                  <span class="cr"><i class="cr-icon glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></i></span>
                </label>
              </div>
            </td>
            <td class="col-lg-1 col-md-1 col-sm-2 col-xs-2">
              <a href="/dialog/22/" class="vibrate">
                <img class="media-photo" src="/images/avatar/113f51ef4b8c25e81a54736d0337db75.jpg">
              </a>
            </td>
            <td class="col-lg-8 col-md-8 col-sm-6 col-xs-5">
              <div class="media">
                <a href="/dialog/22/" class="vibrate">
                  <div class="title pull-left"><strong>elmuza193</strong></div>
                  <div class="clearfix"></div>
                  <div class="">test в дар, 3 мес.</div>
                  <p class="summary">
                    <span class="text-muted">dsfdfd</span>
                  </p>
                </a>
              </div>
            </td>
            <td class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-3 col-xs-3 text-right">
              <div class="text-muted FS12">08.04.2017 18:03</div>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td class="VAM col-lg-1 col-md-1 col-sm-1 col-xs-1 text-center">
              <div class="checkbox M0">
                <label class="M0 vibrate">
                  <input type="checkbox" name="del_dialog_one[]" value="23" class="vibrate">
                  <span class="cr"><i class="cr-icon glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></i></span>
                </label>
              </div>
            </td>
            <td class="col-lg-1 col-md-1 col-sm-2 col-xs-2">
              <a href="/dialog/23/" class="vibrate">
                <img class="media-photo" src="/images/avatar/113f51ef4b8c25e81a54736d0337db75.jpg">
              </a>
            </td>
            <td class="col-lg-8 col-md-8 col-sm-6 col-xs-5">
              <div class="media">
                <a href="/dialog/23/" class="vibrate">
                  <div class="title pull-left"><strong>elmuza193</strong></div>
                  <div class="clearfix"></div>
                  <div class="">лорпа</div>
                  <p class="summary">
                    <span title="Ваше сообщение" class="glyphicon glyphicon-share-alt"></span> <span class="text-muted">ggg</span>
                  </p>
                </a>
              </div>
            </td>
            <td class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-3 col-xs-3 text-right">
              <div class="text-muted FS12">08.04.2017 14:31</div>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td class="VAM col-lg-1 col-md-1 col-sm-1 col-xs-1 text-center">
              <div class="checkbox M0">
                <label class="M0 vibrate">
                  <input type="checkbox" name="del_dialog_one[]" value="24" class="vibrate">
                  <span class="cr"><i class="cr-icon glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></i></span>
                </label>
              </div>
            </td>
            <td class="col-lg-1 col-md-1 col-sm-2 col-xs-2">
              <a href="/dialog/24/" class="vibrate">
                <img class="media-photo" src="/images/avatar/5e522636a001a6f5e5b2ff3300f6d6e4.jpg">
              </a>
            </td>
            <td class="col-lg-8 col-md-8 col-sm-6 col-xs-5">
              <div class="media">
                <a href="/dialog/24/" class="vibrate">
                  <div class="title pull-left"><strong>Svetlana</strong></div>
                  <div class="clearfix"></div>
                  <div class="">gdfgfdgdfg</div>
                  <p class="summary">
                    <span title="Ваше сообщение" class="glyphicon glyphicon-share-alt"></span> <span class="text-muted">uuu</span>
                  </p>
                </a>
              </div>
            </td>
            <td class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-3 col-xs-3 text-right">
              <div class="text-muted FS12">08.04.2017 14:48</div>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td class="VAM col-lg-1 col-md-1 col-sm-1 col-xs-1 text-center">
              <div class="checkbox M0">
                <label class="M0 vibrate">
                  <input type="checkbox" name="del_dialog_one[]" value="25" class="vibrate">
                  <span class="cr"><i class="cr-icon glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></i></span>
                </label>
              </div>
            </td>
            <td class="col-lg-1 col-md-1 col-sm-2 col-xs-2">
              <a href="/dialog/25/" class="vibrate">
                <img class="media-photo" src="/images/avatar/113f51ef4b8c25e81a54736d0337db75.jpg">
              </a>
            </td>
            <td class="col-lg-8 col-md-8 col-sm-6 col-xs-5">
              <div class="media">
                <a href="/dialog/25/" class="vibrate">
                  <div class="title pull-left"><strong>elmuza193</strong></div>
                  <div class="clearfix"></div>
                  <div class="">dfdfds</div>
                  <p class="summary">
                    <span title="Ваше сообщение" class="glyphicon glyphicon-share-alt"></span> <span class="text-muted">gfdgfdgf</span>
                  </p>
                </a>
              </div>
            </td>
            <td class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-3 col-xs-3 text-right">
              <div class="text-muted FS12">08.04.2017 14:30</div>
            </td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  </form>
```

Comment: Здравствуйте! Позволю себе спросить, после того как вы написали данный вопрос, вы его смотрели? Ваш **HTML** кажется вам неплохим? Вы можете отредактировать код, нажмите кнопку в редакторе "Привести в порядок".

Comment: "привел в порядок"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ваша функция проверяет чекбоксы и меняет их состояние. Первый чекбокс один из набора, соответственно по нажатию он сперва меняет состояние а после выполняет функцию, где успешно меняет своё состояние снова.

```
for (i = 1; ... // теперь, если он первый в ДОМЕ он не будет менять состояние
```

А лучше объедините все инпуты, кроме первого, в набор и обращайтесь к нему.

Comment: спасибо. Верно сказали !